# AngularJS Show hide div with fade in/out effect not working

Tags: css, angularjs

i am new in angular. so i run lots of small code finding from internet just for learning purpose. so now i was trying to learn animation with angular. bad luck the code i try to run because it is not working.

### code snippet

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope',
  function MainController($scope) {
    $scope.animate = false;
    $scope.play = function() {
      $scope.animate = !$scope.animate;
    }

  }
]);
```

here is js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/mvL0o2ew/

Comment: The angular version you are using is probably not compatible. Your snippet works fine using `1.2.23/angular.min.js` and `1.2.13/angular-animate.min.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include `angular.js` file itself. So include it, will work then.

Demo :

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.animate = false;
  $scope.play = function() {
    $scope.animate = !$scope.animate;
  }
});
```

```css
.animate-show,
.animate-hide {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 1s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 1s;
  -ms-transition: all linear 1s;
  -o-transition: all linear 1s;
  transition: all linear 1s;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide-remove,
.animate-hide.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block !important;
}

.animate-hide.ng-hide-add,
.animate-show.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular-animate.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  <button ng-click="play()">play</button>
  <div id='wrapper' ng-show="animate" class="animate-show animate-hide">TEST HERE</div>
</body>
```

Comment: can u tell me about the above css. how it is related with `animate-show and animate-hide`

Comment: observe the `html` part in dev tool, before and after `button` click, basically `ng-hide` class gets `added\removed` by angular, and you have written `css` part for same , which takes effect.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving an error in the console:

```
angular.js:12520 TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate-show' of undefined
    at lookup (angular-animate.js:365)
    at performAnimation (angular-animate.js:688)
    at Object.removeClass (angular-animate.js:583)
    at Object.ngShowWatchAction [as fn] (angular.js:27760)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15896)
    at ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:16160)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:23618)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (angular.js:3346)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3334)
```

you need to include properly the correct ng-animage module and it's classes